# echarts - visualMap according to y axis

Tags: echarts

I am trying to add a visual map according to the y axis in echarts.

Taking one of their example:
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-pieces

The results looks as follow:

[image: x axis]

what I'm trying to achieve is:

[image: y axis]

Obviously here, I have just rotated the picture by 90 degree.
How can this be achieve in echarts directly (so not by saving the picture first)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be inverting the axis, data index, and visual map axis. See chart options below:

```
option = {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    xAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        boundaryGap: [0, '30%'],
        position: 'top'
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false 
    },
    visualMap: {
        type: 'piecewise',
        show: false,
        dimension: 1,
        seriesIndex: 0,
        pieces: [{
            gt: 1,
            lt: 3,
            color: 'rgba(0, 180, 0, 0.5)'
        }, {
            gt: 5,
            lt: 7,
            color: 'rgba(0, 180, 0, 0.5)'
        }]
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            smooth: 0.6,
            symbol: 'none',
            lineStyle: {
                color: 'green',
                width: 5
            },
            markLine: {
                symbol: ['none', 'none'],
                label: {show: false},
                data: [
                    {yAxis: 1},
                    {yAxis: 3},
                    {yAxis: 5},
                    {yAxis: 7}
                ]
            },
            areaStyle: {},
            data: [
                [200, '2019-10-10'],
                [400, '2019-10-11'],
                [650, '2019-10-12'],
                [500, '2019-10-13'],
                [250, '2019-10-14'],
                [300, '2019-10-15'],
                [450, '2019-10-16'],
                [300, '2019-10-17'],
                [100, '2019-10-18']
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Result:

[See on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1ID1.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’m currently on holidays and will only be able to test it in few weeks but looking at the code you posted it looks like the solution I was looking for. Thanks.